# Register scripts located in child theme?

Tags: scripts, wp-register-script

I'm having a lot of trouble registering scripts located in a child theme folder:

This works fine:

```
function register_scripts() {
    wp_register_script( 'newsletter', get_template_directory_uri() . '/scripts/scripts.js', array( 'jquery-migrate' ), null );
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_scripts' );
```

However it points to the parent theme folder and not the child, when I try to point to the child theme folder, nothing at all happens:

```
function register_scripts() {
    wp_register_script( 'newsletter', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/scripts/scripts.js', array( 'jquery-migrate' ), null );
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_scripts' );
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you clarify "nothing at all happens"? Is the script registered with a wrong url or not at all?

Comment: Hi Kraftner, what happens is that the script doesn't appear on the html at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that none the options you has posted actually works. You are only registering the script, you need to enqeue them. Also, you should use `wp_enqueue_scripts()` action hook instead of `init()`.

```
    function register_scripts() {
        wp_register_script( 'newsletter', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/scripts/scripts.js', array( 'jquery-migrate' ), null );
        wp_enqeue('newsletter');
    }
   add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'register_scripts' );
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't see how the first block of code works and not the second since in both cases all you are doing is *registering* the script, not enqueueing it. If you don't enqueue nothing will show up on the front end at all.

```
function register_scripts() {
  wp_register_script( 'newsletter', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/scripts/scripts.js', array( 'jquery-migrate' ), null );
  wp_enqueue_script('newsletter'); // you need this
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'register_scripts' );
```

The other possibility is that your enqueueing code is elsewhere and is running before the script is registered.

Also note that the correct hook to be enqueueing scripts is `wp_enqueue_scripts`, not `init`.

> > wp_enqueue_scripts is the proper hook to use when enqueuing items that
> >     are meant to appear on the front end. Despite the name, it is used for
> >     enqueuing both scripts and styles.
>
> http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts

That should be what other code assumes, so you may be having trouble with timing because of that.

Comment: Extended explanation than mine ;)

Comment: @cybnet : didn't even see your answer-- exactly the same timestamp :)